# How to get rails to update the page with js after a jquery $.get call?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, unobtrusive-javascript

### Summary: How can I update the original page when the call is from js?

This original erb link works:

### links view

```
# app/views/links/index.html.haml
= link_to 'verify', verify_link_path(id: link.id, table_row: index),
  class: 'verify',  title: 'Verify this link', remote: true
```

### links controller

```
  def verify_link
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    if @link.valid_get?
      @link.update_attribute(:verified_date, Time.now)
    end 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end 
  end
```

### links verify js erb

```
# app/views/links/verify_link.js.erb 
<%- if @link.verified_date %>
  $("span#verify_link_<%=params['table_row']%>").html('<span class="done">Verified</span>');
<%- else %>
  $("span#verify_link_<%=params['table_row']%>").html('<span class="undone">Unverified</span>');
<%- end %>
```

which works well as it shows either verified or unverified

I've switched to use js:

### links view:

```
%a{href: "#", :data => {verifying_link: 'yes', id: link.id, table_row: index}}
  verify_via_js
```

### links verifying link js:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/verifying_link.js.erb

$(function(){
  $("a[data-verifying-link]='yes'").click(function(){
    // spinner here
    a=$(this).parent()
    a.html('-spinner-')
    var id= $(this).data("id");
    var row = $(this).data("tableRow");
    $.get("/verify_link/"+id+"&table_row="+row);
    a.html('DONE') // temp hack
  }); 
});
```

The record gets updates in the db and I am getting DONE in the ui (the temp hack) but I actually want to have the original verified/unverified work as was done in `verify_link.js.erb`

However is feels as if `app/views/links/verify_link.js.erb` isn't being called by the controller after the jquery `$.get` call to `verify_link` (hence the hack to show 'DONE').

If I refresh the browser page I see the date has been updated.

The server log shows

```
Started GET "/verify_link/386&table_row=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-03 15:14:50 -0400
Processing by LinksController#verify_link as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"386&table_row=2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Link Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `links`.* FROM `links` WHERE `links`.`id` = 386 LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  UPDATE `links` SET `verified_date` = '2014-08-03 19:14:51', `updated_at` = '2014-08-03 19:14:51' WHERE `links`.`id` = 386
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `links` WHERE (1 = 1 AND position = 354)
   (61.5ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered links/verify_link.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 868.2ms (Views: 2.4ms | ActiveRecord: 63.7ms)
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the most recent output at the bottom of the question.

Comment: two things your id being sent to the server is `{"id"=>"386&table_row=2"}` and in your controller you have Link.find(params[:id]) so that could cause the problem but in your logs your user and link are loaded correctly. Can you verify using a debugger that proper link is being loaded. Also your js.erb template is rendered so your js should work

Answer (score 1):

A way to do what you want is in the controller return @link in json format, and in your verifying_link.js.erb file you have to modify the ajax function:

```
$.get("/verify_link/"+id+"&table_row="+row, function(data) {
  if (data.link.verified_date !== undefined) {
   $("span#verify_link_"+row).html('<span class="done">Verified</span>');
  } else {
   $("span#verify_link_"+row).html('<span class="undone">Unverified</span>');
  }
});
```

the respond in the controller can be like this:

    `respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @link.to_json }
    end`

In this solution you don´t need the file verify_link.js.erb

Comment: Partly working (updates the db) but always updates ui with 'Unverified' unless I actually reload the page, in which case I see the actual date (because the db updates did work).

Comment: Please be more specific about the controller.  I tried adding format.json but just get errors - it led to a `500 Internal Server Error` and `<h1>Template is missing</h1>
<p>Missing template links/verify_link, application/verify_link with {:locale=&gt;[:en], :formats=&gt;[:json], :handlers=&gt;[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * &quot;/home/durrantm/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/app/views&quot;
</p>`

Comment: I tried switching to that in the controller but it never updated the page past the '-spinner-' link text.  Switching back to format.js it at least updates the page (though always with Unverified even if that is not the case).